# How to model a currencies, money, and banks that exchange money between currencies?

Tags: haskell, types

Hey so I was reading [this post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/10/typed-language-tdd-part2/) on type-driven development in Java. I had trouble grokking the Java types, so I tried writing it in Haskell. However, I have two problems:

1. I don't know how to implement the difference between a currency and an actual bit of money. At first I thought the currency was just the type of the money (and I think that makes sense) like this `data Dollar = Dollar Double`, where a value like `Dollar 4.0` is money, and `Dollar` the type is the currency. And I think `Dollar :: Double -> Dollar` would be something not exported.
2. That leads to the problem that I can't model a bank that exchanges money. I was thinking something like`exchange :: (Money a, Money b) =>[ExchangeRate] -> a -> b`.  Then a bank is just an object that contains a collection of ExchangeRates, but I don't know what type ExchangeRate is.

The code I have so far is:

```
class Money m where
    money :: (Money m) => Double -> m
    amount :: (Money m) => m -> Double
    add :: (Money m) => m -> m -> m
    add a b = money $ amount a + amount b

class (Money a, Money b) => ExchangeablePair a b where

newtype Dollar = Dollar Double
                 deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Money Dollar where
    money = Dollar
    amount (Dollar a) = a

newtype Franc = Franc Double
                 deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Money Franc where
    money = Franc
    amount (Franc a) = a

instance ExchangeablePair Dollar Franc where
```

EDIT: I still want the safety of something like this: `buyAmericanBigMac :: Dollar -> (BigMac, Dollar)`.

Comment: [Related question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58261/using-phantom-types-to-represent-amounts-and-exchange-rates-of-currencies/58368#58368)

Comment: I tend to think of currencies as Units of Measure and do things in the F# style.  Also, don't use floating point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First note that to be safe, `exchange` should have type

```
exchange :: (Money a, Money b) => [ExchangeRate] -> a -> Maybe b
```

because if you don't have `a` or `b` in your list of rates you can't return anything.

For `ExchangeRate` we could use:

```
newtype ExchangeRate = Rate { unrate :: (TypeRep, Double) }
  deriving Show
```

The `TypeRep` is a unique "fingerprint" for a type. You can get a `TypeRep` by calling `typeOf` on something with a `Typeable` instance. Using this class we can write a type safe lookup for exchange rates:

```hs
findRate :: Typeable a => [ExchangeRate] -> a -> Maybe Double
findRate rates a = lookup (typeOf a) (map unrate rates)
```

Then we can implement your exchange function:

```hs
exchange :: forall a b. (Money a, Money b) => [ExchangeRate] -> a -> Maybe b
exchange rates a = do
  aRate <- findRate rates a
  bRate <- findRate rates (undefined :: b)

  return $ money (bRate * (amount a / aRate))
```

Here we use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension so we can write `undefined :: b` (note we need to write `forall a b.` as well for this to work)

Here's a minimal working example. Instead of `[ExchangeRate]` I've used a `HashMap` (it's faster and stops users from combining exchanges rates that don't belong together).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Exchange
  ( Dollar
  , Franc
  , exchange

  , sampleRates
  , sampleDollars
  ) where

import Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import Data.Typeable

class Typeable m => Money m where
  money  :: Money m => Double -> m
  amount :: Money m => m -> Double
  add    :: Money m => m -> m -> m
  add a b = money $ amount a + amount b

newtype Dollar = Dollar Double
  deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)

instance Money Dollar where
  money = Dollar
  amount (Dollar a) = a

newtype Franc = Franc Double
  deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)

instance Money Franc where
  money            = Franc
  amount (Franc a) = a

newtype ExchangeRates = Exchange (HashMap TypeRep Double)
  deriving Show

findRate :: Typeable a => ExchangeRates -> a -> Maybe Double
findRate (Exchange m) a = HM.lookup (typeOf a) m

exchange :: forall a b. (Money a, Money b) => ExchangeRates -> a -> Maybe b
exchange rates a = do
  aRate <- findRate rates a
  bRate <- findRate rates (undefined :: b)

  return $ money (bRate * (amount a / aRate))

sampleRates :: ExchangeRates
sampleRates = Exchange $ HM.fromList
  [ (typeOf (Dollar 0), 1)
  , (typeOf (Franc 0) , 1.2)
  ]

sampleDollars :: Dollar
sampleDollars = Dollar 5
```

Then you can write

```hs
> exchange sampleRates sampleDollars :: Maybe Franc
Just (Franc 6.0)
```

---

As other other people have mentioned, `Double` isn't really suitable because you can get floating point errors. If you're doing anything with real money I'd recommend using [scientific](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.3.3).

Comment: Wow, I head no idea that something like Typeable existed. Thanks.

Comment: Using floating point representations like `Double` can cause some serious issues with financial stuff (floating point errors can lead to very important inaccuracies, which can definitely add up over a bunch of operations). I would suggest using a fixed point representation instead, so you can represent numbers exactly down to the cent (or fraction of a cent, if the use case calls for it). There's at least one package on Hackage for fixed point arithmetic (I'm sure there's more too).

Answer (score 7):

No, don't uses typeclasses. Let's start with the basics:

So, you want to represent different currency types ? Let's use a simple algebric data type:

```
data CurrencyType = Dollar | Franc deriving (Show)
```

You want to represent money, again use a simple data type:

```
data Money = Money {
      amount :: Double,
      mType :: CurrencyType
    } deriving (Show)
```

Some demo in ghci:

```
*Main> let fiveDollars = Money 5 Dollar
*Main> fiveDollars
Money {amount = 5.0, mType = Dollar}
```

Now, you want the ability to convert money from one currency type to
another. This again can be achived by a simple function:

```
convertMoney :: CurrencyType -> Money -> Money
convertMoney Dollar money = undefined -- logic for Converting money to Dollar                
convertMoney Franc money = undefined -- logic for converting money to Franc
```

My general rule for going to typeclasses is when I want to represent some particular abstraction which has some well defined laws. For most of the cases, simple data types and the functions operating on them will make a good case.

---

**UPDATE** based on your comments: If you want the ability to declare your own type of money, then you can follow this approach:

```
data CurrencyType a = CurrencyType a deriving (Show)

data Dollar = Dollar deriving (Show)

data Money a = Money Double (CurrencyType a) deriving (Show)
```

Demo in ghci:

```
λ> let fiveDollars = Money 5 (CurrencyType Dollar)
λ> fiveDollars
Money 5.0 (CurrencyType Dollar)
```

Now let's say you want to define another currency `Franc`. Then just define a datatype for it:

```
data Franc = Franc deriving (Show)
```

And you can then define money out of it:

```
λ> let fiveFranc = Money 5 (CurrencyType Franc)
λ> fiveFranc
Money 5.0 (CurrencyType Franc)
```

`>> I can't write a function that only takes Dollars at compile time.`

Well, you can.

```
convertFromDollar :: Money Dollar -> Money Franc
convertFromDollar x = undefined -- Write your logic here
```

Comment: But I see two problems with this. 1, someone else can't declare their own type of money (though I'm not sure how problematic this is). 2, more important is that I can't write a function that only takes Dollars at compile time. That adds a whole class of errors.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka I updated my answer to include your other use cases.

Comment: Okay thanks. After looking at both answers and the link from Gallais, I understand that I should make Money have some Currency as a phantom type. This makes sense now http://blog.jakubarnold.cz/2014/07/08/using-phantom-types-for-extra-safety.html.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka: This is a good approach. However, you'll run into a bit of difficulty when you want to have a dynamic set of exchange rates. (Like your `[ExchangeRate]`.) I'm writing an answer right now that handles it, but it's a bit awkward.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis Yeah, I just hit that problem. I tried `data Rate a b = (Currency a, Currency b) => Rate Double`, since I think it makes sense encoding the currencies in the type. But I'm not sure how to code a collection of Rates where the currencies are different. * And hey, I know you from Quora!

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka: I figured out an approach which I'm writing up now. It only sacrifices type safety in one place, which lets you expose a safe interface. I'll add an answer once I finish writing it.

Comment: @RamithJayatilleka: Actually, never mind. cchalmers just wrote an answer that is very similar to what I was going for, so you should just take a look at theirs instead. It will help you have the dynamic map of exchange rates that you want.

Answer (score 1):

How I would implement it in Haskell based on how I've done it in PHP at work:

```
module Money where


-- For instance Show Money
import Text.Printf


-- Should perhaps be some Decimal type
type Amount = Double


-- Currency type
data Currency = Currency { iso4217 :: String } deriving Eq

instance Show Currency where
    show c = iso4217 c


-- Money type
data Money = Money { amount :: Amount, currency :: Currency }

instance Show Money where
    show m = printf "%0.2f" (amount m) ++ " " ++ show (currency m)


-- Conversion between currencies
data BasedRates = BasedRates { base :: Currency, rate :: Currency -> Amount }

type CrossRates = Currency -> Currency -> Amount

makeCrossRatesFromBasedRates :: BasedRates -> CrossRates
makeCrossRatesFromBasedRates (BasedRates { base=base, rate=rate }) = 
    \ fromCurrency toCurrency -> rate toCurrency / rate fromCurrency


convert :: CrossRates -> Currency -> Money -> Money
convert crossRates toCurrency (Money { amount=amount, currency=fromCurrency }) 
    = Money { amount = crossRates fromCurrency toCurrency * amount, currency=toCurrency }



-- Examples

sek = Currency { iso4217 = "SEK" }
usd = Currency { iso4217 = "USD" }
eur = Currency { iso4217 = "EUR" }

sekBasedRates = BasedRates {
    base = sek,
    rate = \currency -> case currency of
        Currency { iso4217 = "SEK" } -> 1.0000
        Currency { iso4217 = "USD" } -> 6.5432
        Currency { iso4217 = "EUR" } -> 9.8765
}

crossRates = makeCrossRatesFromBasedRates sekBasedRates

usdPrice = Money { amount = 23.45, currency = usd }
sekPrice = convert crossRates sek usdPrice
eurPrice = convert crossRates eur usdPrice
```